# negation pseudoclass on CSS3 does not work on childs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying the :not pseudoclass selector, I want everything on the page to have color blue except the childs of a div which class="pag", so I wrote:

```
:not(.pag > p){
    color:blue;
}

<div class="pag">
                    <p>First</p>
                    <p>Second</p>
                    <p>Thirt</p>
                    <article>Blah blah blah</article>
 </div>
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Can somebody explain me why?

http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9pT/

Comment: `:not()` doesn't allow anything other than a single simple selector. That means either `:not(.pag)` or `:not(p)`, but not something like what you have because it contains two simple selectors *and* a child combinator `>`. You won't be able to use one selector to accomplish what you are looking for, but I have to question the need to apply `color` to every element instead of just applying it to `body` and letting it inherit naturally.

Comment: @BoltClock this was not a "real" world example, I was just trying the :not selector to check how it works, the page is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine if you simplify the selector:

```
.pag > :not(p){
    color:blue;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rc9pT/1/).

Albeit this 'works fine' only with the caveat that you have to specify a selector, with this approach, for *every* parent-child relationship; which may become burdensome.

I suspect that it's the simplicity that's required:

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

A 'simple selector' is defined as:

> either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or pseudo-class.

This seems to imply that any selector incorporating combinators (such as white-space, `>`, `+` or `~`, among others) is not 'simple', unfortunately.

References:

- [Negation (`:not()`) pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation).
- [Simple selector definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Comment: That's only every child of `.pag` that isn't a `p`, though, and not any elements outside of `.pag`.

Comment: So its not possible to have complex selectors on :not. Thank you.

Comment: @BoltClock: indeed, but you're better with CSS than I am (by *far*): I just re-read the spec for 'simple selectors,' is my conclusion correct? I'm pretty sure that I've, previously, used descendant selectors as a 'simple' selector... :-/

Comment: Yes, your conclusion is correct. A simple selector and a combinator are two different things entirely. If you have two simple selector sequences (or as Selectors 4 calls them, compound selectors) separated by a combinator, then the entire thing is, as Selector 4 calls it, a complex selector. The CSS2 definition of "simple selector" happened to be either the current definition, *or* the same as a compound selector. Combinators have always been combinators since CSS2 however, and none of these terms were very well-defined in CSS1.

Comment: @BoltClock since you mention Selectors 4, worth noting that Selectors 4 will actually allow complex selectors as an argument to :not(), correct? http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#negation

Comment: @CupawnTae: Yes, but only in the complete profile for now. It's unclear if the CSS profile will allow it yet - but implementations are always free to give it a shot. (It looks like the latest ED as of this writing removed all restrictions from :matches() and :not(), which is interesting.)

Comment: @BoltClock yeah, hopefully that means the browser guys are happy it can be done. I hadn't read that part of the spec before, so I didn't see the more restricted version, interesting indeed.